# Can I generate the XPath expression of the HTML page through my Java code?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Using Selenium in Java, how can I get an XPath at runtime? For example, can I generate the XPath to an HTML element through my Java code?

Because the environment will change in the future, I don't want to use [Firebug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29) or other such tools to solve the problem. In the new environment, the items will be same, but the id or XPath expression will differ. I want my code to work in any environment.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Please give an example of an XPath in your current environment (and the corresponding HTML) and in the "new environment" (and the corresponding HTML).

Comment: You can of course "generate" an XPath for a given `Element`, but how would you locate the `Element` in first place? If you look up the `Element` by different criteria (such as outlined in below's answers, e.g. link text, …), why would you still need an XPath?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. Your Java code is based on locators (id, class, `xpath`, etc.) that you find in the HTML content, and your code can't do it for itself.

As for your problem, ID's don't change from environment to environment and usually neither are classes. Try to locate elements by those locators and try to avoid `xpath`. That way, you shouldn't have a problem running your code in any environment.